# Homotopy of spheres $\pi_{n+1}(S^n) \simeq \mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I have a problem: I have to prove that 
$$ \pi_{n+1}(S^n) \simeq \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} $$
when $n \ge 3$.
I know the Freudenthal suspension theorem and the Hopf fibration. Is there an easy method to do this?

Comment: You only need to look for $\pi_4(S^3)$, since you can use suspensions.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Consider the Hopf map $p:S^3\to S^2$, representing the generator of $\pi_3(S^2)$. The suspended map $\Sigma p: S^4\to S^3$ represents the generator of $\pi_4(S^3)$.

Comment: I know that I can use suspention, but I don't know how can I calculate $\pi_4(S^3)$...

Comment: Hum, this is not so easy. See the Hu's book, Chap. XI, Section 15. What you want is the Theorem 15.1 and the references therein. http://books.google.com.br/books?id=iVhMPU0X2G4C&lpg=PP1&hl=pt-PT&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: My favorite proof involves Pontrjagin's framed cobordism construction, as well as the fun fact that $\pi_1(SO(3))$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: My favorite proof uses the long exact sequence of a fibration, and a spectral sequence argument involving the cohomology of $\mathbb{CP}^\infty$.  See chapter 9 of Kirk and Davis, *Lecture Notes in Algebraic Topology*.

Comment: But if we want only prove that it contains only two component, what we have to use?